# Integrating ajax with django

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I am trying to learn how to integrate ajax with django. When I click the button, the javascript function change() changes the content of the button to 'X' and then ajax is evaluated. But the control is not passed from the client to server side on button click as ajax neither returns success nor failure. It's been two days since I am stuck with ajax.
Here is the full code:

url file:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from game import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^handler/',views.index,name='index'),
    url(r'^$',views.home,name='home'),
]
```

views file:

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import Http404
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
@csrf_exempt
def index(request):
    print "xyx"
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return HttpResponse("sucess")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("failure")
@csrf_exempt
def home(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request,"game/home.html",context)
```

home.html file:

```
<head>
<head>
<script>
function change()
{   
    var y = document.getElementById("one");
    y.value = 'X';
    $.ajax({
        url:"127.0.0.1:8000/handler/",
        type:"POST",
        data:{},
        cache:false,
        success:function(data) {
            var x = document.getElementById(data);
            x.value = 'O';
            alert("sucess");
        },
        error:function(error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type = "button" id = "one" onclick="change()"></input>
</body>
</html>
```

Console output:

```
(django)shivam@shivam-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~/Python/django/django/django_test$ python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
December 05, 2015 - 18:48:10
Django version 1.9, using settings 'django_test.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[05/Dec/2015 18:48:16] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 453
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You function `index` doesnt returns any http response. Just after `print` return a JsonResponse. Also all post calls must end with a trailing slash. If you face any such issue related to client end, check the console and you will find the cause.

Edited:

The issue is that you didnt included jquery in your html. I've included jquery and instead of absolute url, I've used relative url. The only issue remains is there is no element with id `data`. Fix that and you'll be good to go. :)

```
<head>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
function change()
{   
    var y = document.getElementById("one");
    y.value = 'X';
    $.ajax({
        url:"/handler/",
        type:"POST",
        data:{},
        cache:false,
        success:function(data) {
            var x = document.getElementById(data);
            x.value = 'O';
            alert("sucess");
        },
        error:function(error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type = "button" id = "one" onclick="change()"></input>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am now returning a httpresponse but the same problem persists.

Comment: can you paste your console output.

Comment: I've updated answer. Replace your code with mine and you are good to go. cheers.

Comment: This helps..Thanks a lot.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to append a `/` to your url in the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"127.0.0.1:8000/handler/",
    type:"POST",
    data:{},
    . . .
```

Comment: I changed that but problem still remains same.